# Show column name and data type in Teradata?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, teradata

Is there a way to get *column name* and *data type* in a `Teradata SQL Assistant 15.0`view?

In `Oracle 11g` you can do something like `desc tablename`  and get a script result set of the following :

> Name                           Null     Type
>
> ---
>
> test_id                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
>   test_name                               VARCHAR2(255)
>   test_department                         VARCHAR2(255)
>   test_year                               TIMESTAMP(6)
>   test_external_id                        NUMBER(10)

So far I've tried `help view viewname` and the result provides all *column names* but the values for the *data type* are all nulls.

Comment: Try `SHOW TABLE TABLE_NAME`

Comment: That would work for a table but not for a view. @SaagarEliasJacky

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use "SHOW VIEW VIEW_NAME" or "HELP COLUMN VIEW_NAME.*" to get all column names and datatype in the **view**.

**Example**

```
HELP COLUMN dbc.Allspace.*
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Column Name     Type    Nullable    Format                          Max Length  
Vproc           I2      N           -(5)9                           2     
DatabaseName    CF      Y           X(30)                           30  
AccountName     CF      Y           X(30)                           30  
TableName       CF      Y           X(30)                           30  
MaxPerm         F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
MaxSpool        F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
MaxTemp         F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
CurrentPerm     F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
CurrentSpool    F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
CurrentTemp     F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
PeakPerm        F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
PeakSpool       F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
PeakTemp        F       N           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
MaxProfileSpool F       Y           ---,---,---,---,--9             8   
MaxProfileTemp  F       Y           ---,---,---,---,--9             8
```

Comment: But how to get this for 15000 number of views?

Answer (score 2):

you can use : `help table tablename` (in case of tables) and `help view viewname` in case of views